# table views only scrolls to textfields bottom edge

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield, swift4

The bottommost cell of my table view is a cell with a textField. When the user taps it, I want to scroll it so that the cell is right above the keyboard.

When I call the `scrollRectToVisible(...)` with `animated` `false` everything works as expected, but when `animated` is set to `true` the table scrolls the cell only so far, that the bottom of the textField is right above the keyboard *(See left picture)*. Yet the bottonInsets should be correct, since I can scroll the cell the last bit manually and the cell sits right how it should *(See right picture)*.

I think the table view scrolling the textField's bottom edge above the keyboard is the default behavior of a table view, but I'm afraid I don't know why it seems to override my own scrolling when I want it animated.

*Left picture:

The textFields bottom edge right above the keyboard (I kept the border style so you can see it better).*

*Right picture:
How I want it. Cell's bottom edge right above the keyboard.*

[image]

```
func repositionTextfieldCell(in tableView: UITableView) {
    guard let textFieldCell = tableView.bottommostCell() else { return }
    guard let keyboardRect = activeKeyboardRect else { return }

    // - Adjust insets

    var bottomInset = keyboardRect.size.height

    tableView.contentInset.bottom = bottomInset
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = bottomInset

    // - Make cell visible

    let x = textFieldCell.frame.minX
    let y = textFieldCell.frame.maxY

    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
                                         size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem.

The behavior seems to be depended on were `scrollRectToVisible(...)` is called. The behavior I described in the question occurs when `scrollRectToVisible(...)` is called in `keyboardDidShow(...)`.

However when you call `scrollRectToVisible(...)` in `keyboardWillShow(...)` and set `animated` to `false` the cell / rect is pushed up by the keyboard sliding in. Which I think looks great.

Answer (score 0):

add this in viewDidLoad() and create a NSlayout constraint for tableview bottom.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
self,
selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
object: nil
)
```

create the function

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    tableBottomConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight
}
}
```

repeat the process to reset the tableBottomConstraint.constant = 0 in keyboardWillHide() method.

Comment: I tried your answer, but changing the bottom constraint just clips the table content and isn't scrolling it :(